# Cakephp custom error page for all errors

Tags: cakephp, error-handling, cakephp-2.1, custom-error-pages

I have this created:

```
<?php

class AppExceptionHandler
{
    public static function handle($error)
    {       
        $this->controller->redirect('www.google.com');
        //echo 'Oh noes! ' . $error->getMessage();
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}

?>
```

The echo will output fine but how do I use a layout or view?  I keep getting this erro:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in ...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [CakePHP AppError extend functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754723/cakephp-apperror-extend-functions)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following method in you AppController.php

```
public function appError($error) {
    //Do whatever you want
    debug($error);
}
```

Comment: i believe appError is deprecated